# Set testcase property value in SoapUI to null

Tags: soapui

I use some property values in `SoapUI`, which should be set to null / be empty in some executions.
If I leave variable's value field simply empty, I get error message when test is executed.

Comment: Would you mind showing how you are using? or where those properties are being read?

Comment: @Rao: I use this in request URL in this form: `${variablename}`.

Comment: How does it makes different if `null` is set as property value? By the way, how the empty value is set to the property currently? If it is thru script, please show the same.

Comment: I set it in a `Properties` step.

Comment: Can you show the test case and its structure? In which step you want to set it null?

Comment: looks like to be a functional issue. Did you trying executing the step without variable. May be URL is not well formed when the variable is empty

Comment: @Gauravkhurana : Thanks, for your help. Prolem was the dot. If variable was empty, first character of url was a dot.